# Generate array of daily avg values from db table (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm

**Context:**
Trying to generating an array with 1 element for each `created_at` day in db table. Each element is the average of the `points` (integer) column from records with that `created_at` day.
This will later be graphed to display the avg number of points on each day.

**Result:**
I've been successful in doing this, but it feels like an unnecessary amount of code to generate the desired result.

**Code:**

```
def daily_avg
    # get all data for current user
    records = current_user.rounds

    # make array of long dates
    long_date_array = records.pluck(:created_at)

    # create array to store short dates
    short_date_array = []

    # remove time of day
    long_date_array.each do |date|
        short_date_array << date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    end 

    # remove duplicate dates
    short_date_array.uniq!

    # array of avg by date
    array_of_avg_values = []

    # iterate through each day
    short_date_array.each do |date|
        temp_array = []

        # make array of records with this day
        records.each do |record|
            if date === record.created_at.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                temp_array << record.audio_points
            end
        end
        # calc avg by day and append to array_of_avg_values
        array_of_avg_values << temp_array.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / temp_array.size
    end
    render json: array_of_avg_values
end
```

**Question:**
I think this is a common `extraction` problem needing to be solved by lots of applications, so I'm wondering if there's a known repeatable pattern for solving something like this?

Or a more optimal way to solve this?

(I'm barely a junior developer so any advice you can share would be appreciated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a lot of unnecessary stuff when you can just go down to SQL to do it (I'm assuming you have a class called `Round` in your app):

```
class Round

  DAILY_AVERAGE_SELECT = "SELECT 
      DATE(rounds.created_at) AS day_date,
      AVG(rounds.audio_points) AS audio_points
    FROM rounds
    WHERE rounds.user_id = ?
    GROUP BY DATE(rounds.created_at) 
"

  def self.daily_average(user_id)
    connection.select_all(sanitize_sql_array([DAILY_AVERAGE_SELECT, user_id]), "daily-average")
  end

end
```

Doing this straight into the database will be faster (and also include less code) than doing it in ruby as you're doing now.

Comment: will created_at be converted to just a date from datetime?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to do something like this:

```
grouped =
records.order(:created_at).group_by do |r|
   r.created_at.strftime('%Y%m%d')
end
```

At first here you generate proper SQL near to that you wish to get in first approximation, then group result records by `created_at` field converted to just a date.

```
points =
grouped.map do |(date, values)|
   [ date, values.reduce(0.0, :audio_points) / values.size ]
end.to_h

# => { "1-1-1970" => 155.0, ... }
```

Then you remap your grouped hash via array, to calculate average values with `audio_points`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `group` and calculations methods built in AR: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations